# How to delete javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, garbage-collection

I want to have a bunch of objects, let's say:

```
function Block() {
  this.canvas;
}

blocks = [];
```

And I will at occasions specify:

```
block[x] = new Block();
```

and then:

```
block.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

But I will also want to delete this new canvas to free up memory sometimes.  Do I just need to do:

```
block.canvas = null; (or whatever the appropriate method is)
```

And then javascript will free up the memory at some stage?  Or is there an explicit way to delete the object and free up the memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, all very useful.  Apparently I can't upvote yet though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Memory, that is taken by objects, that are referenced nowhere, is recovered in JavaScript by the *garbage collection* ([MDN docu on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Memory_Management)).

So in order to free up the memory, you just have to delete all references to your `canvas` objects and in the next run of the garbage collector, the memory will be freed again.

This can be done, like you did, using `block.canvas = null;` or (depending on the objects/properties scope) by `delete block.canvas`.

But be sure, that you remove *every* reference. This can also be references by the DOM or any other object!

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough if you are actually using that canvas to draw objects. If you're adding the canvas to DOM, you also need to remove it from it, otherwise it will remain in memory of course. If you're adding it using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.appendChild), you should remove it using [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild)

---

On a side note, if you are going to have bunch of objects as you say, it's really bad idea to have canvas per object. You should think about having canvas per visual layer.

Answer (score 3):

Most javascript engine uses **reference counting** or **mark-and-swap** as its GC policy, so any object with no reference to global object (window in browser environment) would be freed up at some stage.

So to ensure your `<canvas>` element could be collected, you should make sure:

- No variable or property references this, by running `block.canvas = null` you get things done
- The `<canvas>` element no longer attached to the DOM tree, by running `canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas)` you could make it done

From your provided code, you don't do the **DOM removal**, maybe your `<canvas>` is not attached to DOM tree, but if it is, remember to remove it.

PS: I noticed some answers metion the `delete` keyword to remove the `canvas` property, but it is really not neccessary, GC works as expected just after `block.canvas` is set to `null`, since [a `delete` may cause V8 to run more slowly](http://kendsnyder.com/posts/chrome-v8-creators-with-and-delete-are-dog-slow), my advice is to prevent the usage of `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has an operator named delete:

```
delete block.canvas;
```

Examples: http://www.openjs.com/articles/delete.php

Comment: Use `block.canvas = null` instead. `delete` modify the structure of `block` at runtime, and it's a counterproductive/expensive operation.
See https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/#de-referencing-misconceptions